# can i connect my R query to generate the output in Tableau

Tags: r, tableau-api

I have some R code in my R studio which generates .csv file output.Can i connect that R studio to tableau so that the user will view the final output in Tableau.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I don't yet have commenting permissions so I had to write here.

In Tableau there is a very specific way to use R. You usually connect tableau with Rserve on port `6311` if I remember correctly. You can then take aggregated fields and paas them to R, do your calculations and pass them back to tableau.
These fields have to be either: `STRING`,`BOOLEAN`,`INT`,and `REAL`

Comment: thanks a lot,,I have bunch of codes.How to pass them as STRING,BOOLEAN,INT,and REAL.Do you have any example?

Comment: check out this article here: https://community.tableau.com/thread/236068

Comment: let me know if you need more explanation

Comment: i had gone through this already.I am wondering what to pass in the argument of SCRIPT_STR(). I have R code (containing 10 lines).